# Bootstrap form style won't apply

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so here is my .html.erb file.  As you can see I have the `margin-fix` class applied which just does a `margin-bottom: 10px;`, the problem is this won't apply.

Now below I have the button with the class `sign_in_button` and all styles work fine on that, but will not work on the fields.  They are way to cramped together and need some margin but it just will not work.  All css is applied in the `application.css`. I even tried a `custom.css` which loaded fine but didn't apply styles to the forms only.  I am using the current download of rails just installed a couple of days ago.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 well sign_in">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>    
session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign In</legend>

      <%= f.input :email, :class => 'margin_fix' %>
      <%= f.input :password %>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %> </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign In", :class => 'sign_in_button' %></div>
    </fieldset>
      <% end %>

      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Signing in is easy and secure</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from possible spelling mistakes: You are not using the recommended Bootstrap 3 (which you are apparently using) formatting. You should use `form-group`- and `form-control`- classes. Replace your fieldset with:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Sign In</legend>

  <div class="form-group margin_fix">
    <%= f.input :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :password, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :remember_me, :class => 'form-control', as: :boolean %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", :class => 'sign_in_button' %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

If this does not work, please post the definition of the `margin_fix`-class.

Comment: Well that did fix the spacing without the needed margin fix class, guess I overlooked this but still not fixing the problem of classes not applying.  For example I have a flash message with the class alert being applied based on whether or not it's a notice or alert, which works fine, but when I go to add edit the class it doesn't apply, same thing with the above, it is all held in a <div class="well"> from bootstrap but when I add a margin of 10px to the top of this class it doesn't apply.

Comment: Ok so, I said the sign_in_button class was working.  Well it kept the old style I applied to it but now if I go back and edit that style say to change the color in the css, the update doesn't apply, so I have no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a 'margin-fix' (with a hyphen) class, but in the ERB above the class is called 'margin_fix' (with an underscore).

Is the class called the same thing in the ERB and CSS files?

Comment: Yea just a miss type as I was frustrated with this whole deal.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all of the public/asset files and changed

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

To

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

And now it seems to be working completely fine.